# Is there an eslint rule to ensure the props, emits, methods order inside Vue SFC is always the same?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Basically this [vue-order-in-components](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/order-in-components.html#vue-order-in-components), but then for the setup script in Composition
API? Any other kind of tool would be welcome as well!

Cheers!

Comment: Options API enforces division of code into different properties/options. Object properties being iterable is how such a rule was previously enforceable.  It's not possible to do anything similar with Composition API because code can live in any order you choose, ideally [ordered according to same logical concern](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#more-flexible-code-organization).  Enforcing Options API-like ordering basically defeats the purpose of Composition API.  If Options API ordering is desired, I suggest just using Options API which is still supported in Vue 3

Comment: Note seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is considered *off-topic* on [SO]. Please read [ask] and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any linting tools out there for the composition api because everything is declared within the  block as js/ts and not properties of an object like with the options api.

What my team and I do is use VS Code snippets to both increase productivity and ensure consistency for the order of our vue component code, separated by comment blocks like this:

```
///// imports /////

///// props/emits /////
const props = defineProps({});

const emit = defineEmits<{}>();

///// refs and variables /////

///// computed /////

///// functions /////

///// watchers /////

///// lifecycle /////
onMounted(() => {});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your team use options API instead if you're organizing your code like that?

Comment: The comments are purely for readability, we want all of the benefits that come with using the composition api like shared stateful logic for example but structuring our code like this gives us the best of both worlds.